# Getting ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError when using a component with select

Tags: javascript, angular, select, angular2-template, angular2-forms

Working on an Angular4 app, I want to create an input component that can manage the different components that can appears in a form, like inputs, textarea, checbox or selects.

I did it work, and it's great (or almost) from the controller I create an array of elements with information about the type (input, select, etc), the id, the placeholder, the model, etc...
The only Issue that I'm having is that for the select inputs, when I try to put a default value I always receive the error ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError. It dissapears if I don't try to put a default value.. But as it's and edit form, I try to prepopulate the select with the corresponding value.

I'm using formControls.

The component template is:

```
<select *ngIf="element.type == 'select'" name="{{element.id}}" 
            formControlName="{{model.id}}" class="form-control" id="{{element.id}}">
   <option *ngFor="let item of element.items" [ngValue]="item.id">{{item.text}}</option>
</select>
```

The element object is:

```
import { SelectItem } from './select-item.model';
export class InputForm{
    title : string;
    type : string;
    model : any;
    label : string;
    placeholder : string;
    id : string;
    newRow : boolean = false;
    size : string = "col-md-12";
    required : boolean = false;
    items : SelectItem[] = [];

setSelect(id : string, model : any, label : string, required : boolean, items : SelectItem[], size : number){
        this.id = id;
        this.items = items;
        this.model = model;
        this.label = label;
        this.required = required;
        this.type = "select";
        this.size = "col-md-" + size;
    }
}
```

This is how I instanciate the element:

```
let vat : InputForm = new InputForm();
  vat.setSelect("vat", this.item.vat, 'COMPONENT.PRODUCT.VAT', true, this.vats, 2);
  vat.newRow = true;
  this.formElement.elements.push(vat);
```

Where this.item is the model of the object I'm trying to update and this.vats are all the items that will be options in the select.

And this is how I instanciate the formCOntrol

```
 this.form = new FormGroup({
      vat: new FormControl(new SelectItem(this.item.vat.id, this.item.vat.name), Validators.required)
    });
```

SelectItem is the model that is used to filled the options in the select. So it's the same object type.

So if there I remove the  `new SelectItem(this.item.vat.id, this.item.vat.name)` from the `new FormControl` everything work, excepts that I don;t have the original value selected.

Comment: [ngValue] ? should've be [value] ?

Comment: With `ngValue`, you can set a custom value for select-option form control. With `value`, it will always be coerced to string. @Vega

Comment: this article should give you the insights [Everything you need to know about the `ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError` error](https://blog.angularindepth.com/everything-you-need-to-know-about-the-expressionchangedafterithasbeencheckederror-error-e3fd9ce7dbb4)